# C++ operator Overloading Template Class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a template class that overrides some functions of a given class.
A simple example would be best to describe what I'm trying to do...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class box{
public:
    void print(){ cout << "Good!"; }
};

template <class T>
class shadow{
    T obj;
public:
    T& operator. (void) { return obj; }
};

int main(void){
    shadow<box> t;
    t.print();
}
```

Check in main what I want to do. I want to simulate the call to one of
box' methods through the template class. It seems operator '.' can't be
overloaded. The closest I've managed to get to this, is by overloading
the operator ().

```
T& operator() (void) { return obj; }
```

and calling t().print() in main. Could you propose a better way to do what I'm trying to?
Thanks in advance.

ps: I really have to do it this way, I don't want to use inheritance.

Comment: What do you want to achieve effectively? Sounds like a XY problem for me.

Comment: `operator .` cannot be overloaded, but you can overload `operator *`, then call `t->print()`.

Comment: You could overload `operator*` of `shadow` and use the `t->print()` syntax like smart pointers do.

Comment: @Csq I think you mean `(*t).print()`.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, and `operator->` is needed for `t->print()`, like in your answer. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to overload `T* operator->` and/or `T& operator*()`:

```
template <class T>
class shadow{
    T obj;
public:
    T* operator->() { return &obj; }
    const T* operator->() const { return &obj; }
};
```

where I have omitted `T& operator*()` for brevity, although it makes sense to have both. Then use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    shadow<box> t;
    t->print();
}
```

Alternatively, provide a conversion operator `operator T&();`, and pass `t` to functions with parameters of the template argument type:

```
template <class T>
class shadow{
    T obj;
public:
    operator T&() { return obj; }
    operator const T&() const { return obj; }

void foo(const box& b)
{
  b.print(); // Note: you need to make box::print() a const member function
}

int main()
{
    shadow<box> t;
    foo(t);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the 1st option more...
Though not being what I really had in mind, it's not bad...